# ¿Convertir un objeto a String en PHP?

Tags: php, poo

Muy buenas tras varios meses leyendo, voy a realizar mi primera pregunta.

Estoy estudiando Desarrollo de aplicaciones multiplataforma y tengo un ejercicio que me está dando varios quebraderos de cabeza la verdad a ver si me podéis ayudar. Sobretodo con el fallo que me da ya que creo que el resto del trabajo soy capaz de realizarlo sin ningún problema.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

### Enunciado:

Crear una aplicación en **PHP**. Para ello se tendrán que cumplir los siguientes requisitos:

- Crear una clase contacto.
- Crear una clase agenda.
- Crear un script de inicio `index.php`.

---

- La clase agenda será la responsable de crear 10 contactos.
- La clase agenda será responsable de mostrar todos los contactos.
- La clase agenda será responsable de borrar contactos.

En el script de inicio será necesario crear 10 contactos, mostrar los 10 contactos, borrar tres contactos al azar y volver a mostrar los contactos restantes.

Aquí os dejo como tengo estructuradas las clases:

Clase contact

```
<?php

class Contact
{

    private $name;
    private $phoneNumber;

    function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
         $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setPhoneNumber($phoneNumber)
    {
        $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
         return $this->name;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

---

Clase Agenda

```
class Agenda
{

    private $arrayDeContactos = array();


    function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function getArray()
    {
        return $this->arrayDeContactos;

    }

    public function addContact($contacto)
    {       

        if ($contacto instanceof Contact) {

            $this->arrayDeContactos[]= $contacto;
        }

    }

    public function mostrarArray()
    {

        $this->arrayDeContactos;

        foreach ($this->arrayDeContactos as $key => $value) {

            echo $value;
        }

        return $value;
    }
```

---

El script de incio `index.php`:

```
  <?

    require './contact.php';
    require './agenda.php';

    $contacto_1 = new Contact();
    $contacto_1->setName("Julian");
    $contacto_1->setPhoneNumber("634635306");
    $contacto_2 = new Contact();
    $contacto_2->setName("lamber");
    $contacto_2->setPhoneNumber("654654654");

    $laAgenda = new Agenda();

    $laAgenda->addContact($contacto_1);

    $laAgenda->addContact($contacto_2);


    $laAgenda->mostrarArray();
```

Me muestra el siguiente error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Contact could not be
>   converted to  string in C:\MAMP\htdocs\Ejercicio_Tema_1\agenda.php on
>   line 37

La verdad que no se muy bien como avanzar, sin embargo si utilizo otra función como `print_r` o `var_dump` si que funciona.

Es mi primera publicación así que cualquier feedback es positivo :D

Answer (score 1):

El problema se encuentra en que tu tienes un `array` de contactos y no un `array` de cadenas (el método [print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php) te funciona porque éste método te muestra el objeto de una manera más legible) pero el `echo` no esta preparado para leer ese tipo de variables, entonces debes acceder a los atributos mediante los métodos `getName()` o bien `getPhoneNumber()`:

```
public function mostrarArray()
{

    // $this->arrayDeContactos;
    foreach ($this->arrayDeContactos as $key => $value) {
        echo 'Name: ' . $value->getName() . ' Phone: ' . $value->getPhoneNumber();
    }
    return $value;
}
```

O tambien podrias crear un metodo `toString()` en la clase `contacto`

```
class Contact
{

    private $name;
    private $phoneNumber;

    function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setPhoneNumber($phoneNumber)
    {
        $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->phoneNumber;
    }

    public function toString()
    {
        return "Name: $this->name, Phone: $this->phoneNumber";
    }
}
```

o un metodo que te retorne una cadena y luego llamarla en el metodo `mostrar`

```
public function mostrarArray()
{

    // $this->arrayDeContactos;
    foreach ($this->arrayDeContactos as $key => $value) {
        echo $value->toString();
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Saludos ;)

Comment: Gracias!!! Me ha servido de mucha ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Estas intentando imprimir un **objeto** con `echo` en `mostrarArray`.

```
  public function mostrarArray()
  {
      foreach ($this->arrayDeContactos as $key => $value) {
          echo $value->getName();
      }
  }
```

Comment: wow mil gracias me ha servido de mucho!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errorcitos que se pueden mejorar, te dejo un ejemplo documentado

```
<?php

class Contacto {
    // Como vas a utilizar los datos de esta instancia, no debería ser private, sino public el scope de la variable
    // Podemos reducir mucho codigo si en lugar de utilizarlo separado hacemos un arreglo de datos, dependera de lo pedido
    public $datos = array('nombre' => '', 'telefono' => '');

    // Si no utilizarás el constructor está demás que lo declares, aquí yo le estoy dando utlidad, nos ahorramos una funcion
    public function __construct( string $nombre, string $telefono ) {
        if( !empty( $nombre ) && !empty( $telefono ) ) {
            $this->datos['nombre']   = $nombre;
            $this->datos['telefono'] = $telefono;
        }
    }
}

class Agenda {
    public $contactos = Array();

    // Creamos la funcion que añadira a los contactos
    public function anadirContacto( Contacto $contacto ) {
        if( $contacto instanceof Contacto ) {
            array_push( $this->contactos, $contacto );
        }
    }

    // No es del todo grato hacer impresiones a pantalla desde la función, esto debería ser retornado
    // Al script que se invocó y de ahí ser ciclado, dado el requerimiento lo haremos así.
    public function traerAgenda() {

        // Recuerda que el contacto está encapsulado en un arreglo y luego en un objeto de tipo contacto
        // que tiene como indice principal 'datos', no podrás hacer la impresión directa, debes acceder a los nodos
        foreach( $this->contactos as $contacto ) {
            echo '<b>Nombre: </b>' . $contacto->datos['nombre'] . ' / <b>Teléfono: </b>' . $contacto->datos['telefono'] . '<br>';
        }
        return $this->contactos;
    }

    // Te dejo la funcioón para borrar un contacto
    public function borrarContacto( Contacto $contacto ) {
        if( $contacto instanceof Contacto ) {
            $key = 0;
            // Ciclamos el arreglo y comparamos los nombres, Aquí debería haber un valor único ya que si hay nombres repetidos
            // Borrara la primera ocurrencia
            foreach( $this->contactos as $con ) {
                if( $contacto->datos['nombre'] == $con->datos['nombre'] ) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    $key++;    
                }
            }
            // Eliminamos dependiendo donde haya guardado el index
            unset( $this->contactos[ $key ] );

            // Volvemos a llamar la funcion de traerAgenda
            self::traerAgenda();
        }
    }
}
$agenda   = new Agenda();
$array = [ 
    ['nombre' => 'Alberto', 'telefono' => '159753'],
    ['nombre' => 'Itzel', 'telefono' => '852741'],
    ['nombre' => 'Roberto', 'telefono' => '789644'],
    ['nombre' => 'Erik', 'telefono' => '321654'],
    ['nombre' => 'Sandra', 'telefono' => '951753'],
    ['nombre' => 'María', 'telefono' => '321321'],
    ['nombre' => 'Mario', 'telefono' => '426486'],
    ['nombre' => 'Juan', 'telefono' => '753195'] ];

foreach( $array as $contact ) {
    $contacto = new Contacto( $contact['nombre'], $contact['telefono'] );
    $agenda->anadirContacto( $contacto );    
}

$contactos = $agenda->traerAgenda();
echo '<hr>';

// Borremos a Erik
$agenda->borrarContacto( $contactos[3] );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta corta si lo que deseas es tratar el objeto `Contact` como un `string` es usar el método magico `__toString` algo así:

```
class Contact {

    /* current code here... */

    public function __toString()
    {
        return "Name: $this->name, Phone: $this->phoneNumber\n";
    }

}
```

Ejecuta tu aplicación de nuevo y notaras que ya funciona sin modificar en ningún otro segmento de código. Por otra parte yo son partidario de que una clase tiene una única responsabilidad, así que definiría un recurso de presentación exclusivamente a esta tarea de impresión.

> Ver documentación del método [_toString](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @LambertoLemos si alguna de las solcuiones te fue de utilidad, deberías considerar dar por resuelta la pregunta.